# ORA-12899 when inserting from sqlplus, but ok with jdbc

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, nls

Inserting 'ééééé' into a column defined as varchar(5) runs fine from squirrel sql client (jdbc).
But doing the same insert from sqlplus fails with **ORA-12899** (too long value).

NLS_CHARACTERSET is set to **AL32UTF8**
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS is set to **CHAR**

It look like sqlplus is not honoring these settings...

Where should I look ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same character set:

```
SELECT value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

Result:

```
VALUE
-----------
AL32UTF8
```

I have `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` set to **BYTE**, but I can override this option in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE encoding (name VARCHAR2(5 CHAR));
INSERT INTO encoding VALUES('ééééé');

1 row created.
```

My **NLS_LANG** is: `AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8`, because my server is encoded UTF8.
But if I unset this environment variable:

```
unset NLS_LANG
```

and if i try again:

```
INSERT INTO encoding VALUES('ééééé');
ORA-12899; value too large for column "..."."..."."...." (actual: 10, maximum: 5)
```

so, yo can do a try and set your `NLS_LANG` variable, which is in the format

```
[NLS_LANGUAGE]_[NLS_TERRITORY].[NLS_CHARACTERSET]
```

And it would work. You can obtain this parameters from `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS`.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I had to export a NLS_LANG=".AL32UTF8" environment variable in my bash to get sqlplus using UTF8. LANG was set to fr_FR.UTF-8, and I thought it was enough, but it was not.